# WorkManager CoroutineWorker's stream cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I have the following setup:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
    flowOfEvents
        .onEach(eventChannel::send)
        .launchIn(this)  

    if (isQueueEmpty()) return@coroutineScope Result.success()

    ... 
}
```

What I'm seeing is the following: when `isQueueEmpty()` is true, I return `Result.success()` and I'd expect the `flowOfEvents...launchIn(this)` stream to be disposed/cancelled as well, but I keep receiving events from that stream.

Am I doing something wrong?

Capturing the Job from `launchIn(this)` and explicitly calling `job.cancel()` before each return statement works, but feels unnecessary/wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research, it was made clear that this is a Kotlin coroutines behavior and isn't related to `WorkManager` at all.

- Listening to a `Flow<Event>` is a never-ending job
- By definition, parent coroutines wait for the child coroutines to finish

Given these 2 points, it is now apparent why I kept receiving `Event`s even after I returned from the parent coroutine.

The solution: call `coroutineContext[Job]?.cancelChildren()` before returning from the parent coroutine.

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
    flowOfEvents
        .onEach(eventChannel::send)
        .launchIn(this)  

    if (isQueueEmpty()) {
        coroutineContext[Job]?.cancelChildren()
        return@coroutineScope Result.success()
    }

    ... 
}
```

**Note: calling parent's `cancel()` throws a `CancellationException`, which in the context of a `WorkManager` meant that the `Worker#doWork` method would actually result in a failed job.**